# Android Chrome doesn't play or load videos through Filesystem API

Tags: android, html, google-chrome, video, filesystems

Reproduce the problem:

1. Fetch a video through XMLHTTPRequest from server as blob.
2. Save per FileSystem API on local sandbox filesystem.
3. Create video tag with "FileEntry.toURL"-method.
4. Try to play on Android Chrome -> fails
5. Try to play on Desktop Chrome -> runs

In my opinion it's a very important feature. Because if video loading is working we have the full possibility to implement offline media apps on smartphones and tablets without a native code dependency.

The download seems to be working. But the browser cannot play the video from filesystem. I tried the same use case with images. This is working. see the example at http://sobek-agency.com/html5-file-api/

see http://sobek-agency.com/html5-file-api/

Source code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var _fs;

            var imagefilename = "st-logo.png";
            var videofilename = "st-is-coming.webm";

            var diskSpaceRequired = 20 * 1024 * 1024;

            window.requestFileSystem = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;

            function errorHandler(e) {
              var msg = '';

              switch (e.code) {
                case FileError.QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR:
                  msg = 'QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR';
                  break;
                case FileError.NOT_FOUND_ERR:
                  msg = 'NOT_FOUND_ERR';
                  break;
                case FileError.SECURITY_ERR:
                  msg = 'SECURITY_ERR';
                  break;
                case FileError.INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR:
                  msg = 'INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR';
                  break;
                case FileError.INVALID_STATE_ERR:
                  msg = 'INVALID_STATE_ERR';
                  break;
                default:
                  msg = 'Unknown Error';
                  break;
              };
              console.log(msg);
            }

            function downloadImageAndVideo(fileEntry) {

                console.log('fetch image resource');
                _fs.root.getFile(imagefilename, { create: true }, function (fileEntry) {
                    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xhr.responseType = "blob";
                    xhr.open("GET", imagefilename, true);
                    xhr.onload = function(e) {
                        if (this.status == 200) {
                            var movieBlob = this.response;
                            fileEntry.createWriter(function (fileWriter) {
                                fileWriter.write(movieBlob);
                                fileWriter.onwriteend = function(e) {
                                    var src = fileEntry.toURL();
                                    $('body').append('<h3>Image loading through Filesystem API is working (on Android Chrome!):</h3><img height="150px" src="' + src + '" /><br/><span id="imgInfo"></span><br/>');
                                };
                            }, errorHandler);
                        }
                    };
                    xhr.send();
                });

                console.log('fetch video resource');
                _fs.root.getFile(videofilename, { create: true }, function (fileEntry) {
                    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xhr.responseType = "blob";
                    xhr.open("GET", videofilename, true);
                    xhr.onload = function(e) {
                        if (this.status == 200) {
                            var movieBlob = this.response;
                            fileEntry.createWriter(function (fileWriter) {
                                fileWriter.write(movieBlob);
                                fileWriter.onwriteend = function(e) {
                                    var src = fileEntry.toURL();
                                    $('body').append('<h3>Video loading through Filesystem is not working (on Android Chrome!)</h3><video controls><source src="' + src + '"  type="video/webm"/></video><br/><span id="videoInfo"></span><br/>');
                                };
                            }, errorHandler);
                        }
                    };
                    xhr.send();
                });

            }  

            //request quota and persistent storage
            $(document).ready(function () {
                window.webkitStorageInfo.requestQuota(
                    PERSISTENT,
                    diskSpaceRequired,
                    function (grantedBytes) { 
                        window.requestFileSystem(PERSISTENT, grantedBytes, function(fs) {
                            _fs = fs;
                            downloadImageAndVideo();
                        }, errorHandler);

                    },
                    errorHandler
                );
            });

        </script>
        <title>foo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: For that issue a bug was opened at google code: [link](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=180541)

Answer (score 1):

I have confirmed the issue is reproducible on latest Chrome for Android.
But apparently it's been fixed and is working on the latest build. (no updates but this seems to be same bug http://crbug.com/173588)

Please wait for the fixed build to be public in a few months.